# How to find the X and Y coordinates of a div element on-screen?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a `div` element that gets animated when you hover over it. I want to detect when the div element leaves the point `0, 0`, and when it returns to `0, 0`. I have the base code already, I just don't know the variables I would plug in.

```
var divx = getElementById("div").position.x;
var divy = getElementById("div").position.y;
if (divx === 0 && divy === 0) {
    window.alert("Div has returned to starting position")
```

And to finish off, I am just starting HTML and JavaScript, so if this is a super obvious solution, then I guess I'll have to go do more reasearch.

Comment: can you post the entire code?

Comment: Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve the position (X,Y) of an HTML element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use getBoundingClientRect()

```
var rect = obj.getBoundingClientRect();
```

rect is an object with eight properties: left, top, right, bottom, x, y, width, height

[source from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)